# How do I make the LED stop blinking during network activity with an Intel PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN?

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

I have a hp laptop. It has a network switch that allows to disable wireless networking. It is blue when working, orange when not working. At least, that's what it was with 10.04. Now it is blue when working, but flashes with blue/orange when there is some sort of networking activity. I would like to go back to the time when it just stayed blue if on, rather than showing network activity. How to do that ?

edit: here is the command you asked:

http://pastebin.com/fbGzRpE9

and here is the second one:

http://pastebin.com/iCxpRBxW

Comment: There are various tweaks for that problem, but all depend on the wireless card and the driver. It doesn't actually matter what brand or model of the laptop you have. To identify your wireless hardware, please add the output of `sudo lshw -C network` to the question.

Comment: Thanks, it's an Intel card. How about `modinfo -F parm iwlwifi`?

Comment: see edit once again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following commands should work for you:

```
sudo rmmod iwlwifi

sudo modprobe iwlwifi led_mode=1
```

To make it permanent, run

`gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`,

paste in `options iwlwifi led_mode=1`, then save and close.

Comment: wow you're good. It worked, thanks a lot. You seem to know quite a lot about this hardware wireless stuff, and since you already know what hardware I'm using from the questions you asked, please allow me to give you the link to another question I asked: http://askubuntu.com/questions/168982/wireless-wol-with-laptop

Comment: Options for `led_mode`:  `0` system default, `1` on/off (RF state), `2` blinking (activity), `3` off.