# How do I get wireless Wake-on-Lan work with an Intel 5100 AGN?

Tags: wireless, networking, intel-wireless

How can I make a wireless wol with Intel PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN from a hp laptop ?

Comment: maybe you wanna look up http://johnlewis.ie/wake-on-lan-over-wireless/

Comment: This one offers to wake up a machine just by ping ??? I don't understand how that would work, and it doesn't sound safe to me.

Answer (score 7):

Actually the other answer is quite old and not up to date.

Please use the `iw` tool.

To check whether it's supported: `iw phy0 info`

Check the status: `iw phy0 wowlan show`.

Activate several options: `sudo iw phy0 wowlan enable magic-packet disconnect`.

The [kernel wiki](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/wowlan) has some information as well. If wake on wlan does not work from suspend mode try freeze mode: Close all applications, then `sync && echo freeze | sudo tee /sys/power/state`. This is not as low power, but less than a running system and nice to test whether the magic packets at get there and the driver interprets them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://johnlewis.ie/wake-on-lan-over-wireless/

Also, check if Your wireless card support WakeOnLan, and You must have kernel version >= 3.1

Comment: How would I know if it is supported ? I gave you its reference.

Comment: to check if your chip is supported go to bios and search for wake on lan options.

Comment: There is a boot option, and there is a drop down box with 3 options, disabled, network boot or boot order. I have it set to network boot. ethool eth0 shows pg as wol. Why would the kernel version matter if the OS is not even loaded ??

Comment: I'm almost sure that it won't be in boot options. And as of why kernel >= 3.1

http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=OTgwMg

Comment: Moreover this site seems to say that magic pacckets for wireless lans don't exist, this  one seems to say differently: http://revolutionwifi.blogspot.fr/2010/11/wake-on-wireless-lan.html From what I understood, the link you mentionned offers to wake up by ping. How would that work, and isn't it a security concern ?

Comment: WoWL its like WoL, You must ping PC with magic packet. And Why would it be security concern if You can only WoWL and WoL only in local network.

Comment: Ok. So what is it that you want me to do exactly? If I try what the link says, the output is

 sudo ethtool -s eth0 wol u-->

Cannot set new wake-on-lan settings: Operation not supported


  (not setting wol)

Comment: @roy429, Are you sure your hardware supports it? zuberuber, please summmarize the content of the link in the answer. It's a StackExchange policy to avoid link rot, thank you.