# Wifi stays on during sleep (suspend)

Tags: wireless, suspend

My wifi LED indicator stays on when I suspend Ubuntu.

I don't know if the wifi card stays on itself but I know that I can barely get 2 to 3 hours of sleep time when the wifi is on! But when it is off I get much much longer.

Specs: Ubuntu 12.04 and VAIO VPC-Z135. Wireless chip is Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Can you give us some information on the computer in question for example make and model?

Comment: Yes, edited the question

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you might be among the lucky few who have a wifi chipset that is capable of WoWLAN, the wireless implementation of wake-on-lan.  I've been checking into all of mine for this capability, and unfortunately, only 1 of my several machines has it...

Not sure if it can be disabled, but it might be worth looking into, in your case.

Comment: Inspect the log files `/var/log/pm-{powersave,suspend}.log`. They will show you the system's attempts to suspend/resume. You might get some hints there. I agree with previous posters - Check your BIOS settings for WoWLAN and disable it.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else here looking for answer: like the others say, this very likely has to do with WoWLAN.

I've been trying to enable that on my hardware and in my case, there is no BIOS option for WoWLAN. I can enable/disable it using `iw` via command line though.

From [How do I get wireless Wake-on-Lan work with an Intel 5100 AGN?](https://askubuntu.com/a/896607/692516) :

To check whether it's supported: `iw phy0 info`

Check the status using: `iw phy0 wowlan show.`

And to disable it: `sudo iw phy0 wowlan disable`

I believe your wifi card shouldn't stay on if you disable WoWLAN.

Answer (score 0):

didnt know whether this was solved or not but i thought id post it anyway for future reference, the wake on lan settings or in your case wowlan usually can be disabled in the bios