# Wake-on-Wireless-LAN on Ubuntu - what sleep states will it work from and how to configure it?

Tags: networking, wireless, power-management, iwlwifi, wakeonlan

I have a Intel **AMT** featuring mobo and a **vPro** capable Intel mPCIe wifi card (Centrino Adv-N 6235), and I'm trying to configure my system (running Ubuntu 14.04) to wake via WLAN.

Using `iw` to enable wowlan and following the instructions in [How do I get wireless Wake-on-Lan work with an Intel 5100 AGN?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168982/how-do-i-get-wireless-wake-on-lan-work-with-an-intel-5100-agn), I was able to get wake my system from a *freeze* state (s0) using a magic packet. However, I can't get this to work from *suspend*, and I'd ideally like to be able to wake the system when it's powered down (be able to plug this machine in and wake it via wowlan). Shouldn't enabling wowlan via `iw` configure the system to keep the wifi card powered when suspending?

Could someone please help me check if the wifi card is being powered down on suspend or shutdown? Is this something that requires further configuration within Ubuntu - maybe proprietary drivers? I haven't been able to find very much information on troubleshooting WoWLAN on Ubuntu, just a few guides with info regarding the feature ([this one on kernel.org](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/wowlan) and
[this one in Ubuntu docs](https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/network/network-manager/docs/reference/snap-configuration/wowlan)).

Has anyone here worked with AMT and Ubuntu before? I think AMT also makes use of wake-on-wireless-LAN capabilities.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can not provide a full solution, but advance you one step further:

If you have TLP or similar power saving systems enabled, the wifi adapter will be powered down and wowlan will be disabled in power saving modes, even if you enabled it.

For TLP there’s a setting in `/etc/tlp.conf`, which you have to change to:

```
WOL_DISABLE=N
```

I say partial, because for me, it didn’t help, even after restarting the TLP service. But maybe it needs a reboot or something.

Also, apparently in recent Ubuntu, even network-manager is a snap now (Can Ubuntu miss the key ideas of Unix even *more*?? ;), and the snap has a setting  [documented on its site](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/networkmanager/snap-configuration/wake-on-wlan):

```
snap set network-manager wifi.wake-on-wlan=magic
```

Maybe this helps…

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the same system/setup anymore to test. However, I hope this helps someone!