# Wake on WLAN (WoWLAN) only works from freeze

Tags: 18.04, wakeonlan

I set up Wake on WLAN for my PCIe wireless card with the command `sudo iw phy0 wowlan enable magic-packet disconnect`. This also runs on every boot. Confirming that it is indeed enabled with `sudo iw phy0 wowlan show` returns the below.

```
WoWLAN is enabled:
 * wake up on disconnect
 * wake up on magic packet
```

Unfortunately, when I suspend the system with `sudo systemctl suspend` and try to wakeup from another computer with `wol MAC_ADDRESS`, nothing happens.

However, if I freeze the system with `sync && echo freeze | sudo tee /sys/power/state`, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/896607/903064), I can wake up the system with the `wol` magic packet.

Visibly, the difference between these two commands on the target system is that the fans stop spinning with suspend, and the fans keep spinning with freeze.

`cat /proc/acpi/wakeup` returns enabled for both the wireless interface and its parent PCI slot.

Could it be that my wireless card is losing power in suspend and thus cannot actually receive the magic packet signal? I have disabled power management for the wireless card with `iwconfig wlp5s0 power off`.

Any help with how I can make WoWLAN work with suspend would be much appreciated.